# How to replace a string in SASS partials using webpack?

Tags: sass, webpack, sass-loader

Without having much knowledge about webpack I am trying to replace some strings inside SASS partials using the string-replace-loader (https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-replace-loader).

My webpack config looks like this

```
{
    test: /\.scss/,
    loaders: 'style!css!sass?sourceMap!string-replace?search=mySearch&replace=replaceWith'
}
```

As I understand it replaces 'mySearch' in all files ending with '.scss' with 'replaceWith'.

However, the SASS partials are not replaced. Only files without the underscore. I can see this by using the debug-loader (https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug-loader), because the files with underscore are not even loaded.

How can I make sure these files are loaded as well?